# I'm perplexed about logical structure & physical structure of oracle database

Tags: oracle

Being junior DBA,I'm perplexed about logical structure & physical structure of oracle database. (i.e) **Data blocks,extents,segments,tablespace**,**tables,indexes,procedures** etc., in logical structure.
**Data files,control files, online redo log files** etc., in physical structure of oracle database.

While i come across architecture of oracle database, it is mentioned as

> 1. "Physical data is data viewable at the operating system level. For example, operating system
>      utilities such as the Linux ls and ps can list database files and processes. Logical data
>      such as a table is meaningful only for the database. Physical structure is irrespective of logical structure of oracle
>      database"

eg: renaming a data file(physical structure) doesn't affect any data in tables(logical structure) of oracle database.

and

> 2. "logical structure enable Oracle Database to have fine-grained control of disk space
>      use"

It is also designed as

> 3. tablespace contains one or more datafile
> 4. how logical and physical structures related to each other

I hope, definitely anyone will figure it out this ***(2. 3. & 4. numbered points)*** and i will come out of my stupefaction about oracle database structures.